# Ansible. Dynamically add hostname variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a yaml Ansible inventory with structure like below

```yaml
rpi_wifi:
  children:
    _wifi:
      hosts:
        10.74.47.49 :
        10.74.47.218:
        10.74.47.70 :
```

My goal is to have a playbook that will gather ansible_hostname var from each host and will add it to the new line for each host in the inventory file
So i created something like this

```
- name: Add ansible_hostname to hosts
  hosts: rpi_wifi
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Update inventory file with ansible_hostname_var
      lineinfile:
        path: hosts0.yml
        regexp: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"   
        line: "{{ ansible_hostname }}                   \n {{ ansible_hostname }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

So the final result should be like below

```
rpi_wifi:
  children:
    _wifi:
      hosts:
        10.74.47.49 :
          ansible_hostname: foo
        10.74.47.218:
          ansible_hostname: bar
        10.74.47.70 :
          ansible_hostname: foo-bar
```

At this moment, my main issue is that for some reason, Ansible isn't adding a hostname for each host. It can skip one or more of them, and it happens randomly on every run. I can't understand why, despite this when I'm running it with -vvv option it shows that it has gathered the hostname correctly

The second issue is tabulation in YAML format. My inventory is in yaml format, so i need to have various counts of spaces for my host groups, is there any other way to handle it ?

Comment: The first issue was resolved with `throttle: 1` parameter for the ansible task
Now I'm searching for a way to correctly insert my line saving YAML structure, cuz now it is always at the beginning of the new line when switched to `inserafter` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with this code

```yaml
- name: Update inventory file with ansible_hostname_var
  throttle: 1
  lineinfile:
    backrefs: true
    path: hosts0.yml
    regexp: '^(\s*)({{ inventory_hostname }}:)'
    line: '\1\2\n\1  hostname: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"'
  delegate_to: localhost
```